# Why electrons travel from cathode to conductor end point connected to cathode although they have same potential thus 0 potential difference?

Tags: voltage, current

I have been recently start learning about electricity.
But I can't get onething, Electron travel from high potential to low potential.

So why Electron travel from cathode to conductors end connected to cathode. As both are at same potential(not talking about too much practical that even wire has resistance, I am talking on basic theory part. Vice versa for anode and end of conductor connected to anode.

[image]

Here voltage is 5V and let say potential at  at anode is 0V and at cathode it is 5V (talking from Electron perspective not conventional current) so corresponding red points and blue points are equal.Red points have 0 V and blue has 5 V potential.

So how can Electron travel from cathode to 'conductor end connected to cathode' as same potential vice versa for anode.

Comment: But the wire is full of electrons, wire is not "empty space". And one electron will repel another electron.

Comment: Suppose there indeed is 'zero' voltage across the length of the wire.   That the voltage is indeed exactly same at the battery as it is at the load.   There is then clearly a voltage difference across the load, right?  That will force current to move through the load.   What this does is create a 'vacuum' of electrons on one side of the the load, and an 'excess' of electrons on the other.  But electrons hate that.  So some electrons are 'sucked' from the battery to replenish the vacuum, while others are 'pushed' to the battery to correct the excess.

Comment: @Kyle B , This is the same I thought. BUT I am not sure how much true is it?

Comment: @SureshChandraPal   Well I'm simplifying of course.   But let me propose another thought experiment for you...     You have seen waves in the ocean many time, right?  These waves are how energy is transmitted.  But if you look at the MICRO scale, the WATER MOLECULES are NOT travelling the same speed as the waves.  The energy of the waves rides on the water, but it is not the water flowing.  It is similar in electricity.  The electrons move amazingly slow (inches / hour).  Its the electromagnetic fields around the wire that actually carry the energy.

Comment: Yes...it's not one Electron have to travel across a load to glow it up..but as one Electron move other get automatically move eg. 5 balls in a pipe if one ball we push 1cm from one end , other balk from other hand come out, individually all ball move just 1 cm but there is a system establish. Due to one e- move other automatically move. Right?

Comment: The negative end of the voltage source is pushing the electrons. The positive end is pulling them.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is that it's not *exactly* zero in a normal conductor. The conductor has resistance that isn't zero, a potential difference is generated across it, and that moves the charge carriers. It is close to zero, but not zero.

(Superconductors exist, and their theory is more complex, but then you have to look at the junction between the superconductor and a normal conductor; electrons enter traveling at speed and retain that speed through the superconductor.)

Comment: So there is potential difference in wire? But if it is approximate to zero or very less....than electric field should be weak in wire? As compared between conductor end point, than current should be different? As weak electric weak, weak acceleration thus less current?

Comment: Sir please look at comment of @Kyle B , how much correct it is in ur view?

Comment: The comment about electrons being "sucked" out of the conductor is also a decent model. But they're the same phenomenon: if you remove an electron from one end, that removes its electrical field from the total electrical field, and therefore creates a field gradient.